# MS Access connected to Two Dbs

Tags: mysql, sql-server, azure, ms-access, vba

I am working on a Microsoft Access Project that has a connection to two databases one is SQL Server hosted in Azure, another is MySql hosted on a Linux server.

In my form I am trying to import data from the MySQL into the Azure server.

I have successfully connected to the database and inserted values into my database

```
             From  MySql /Linux        ---- INTO ---->         Azure/SQL
```

both manually inserting through a query and through my code. My code on my form is essentially running a SQL query to select from table MySQL into a SQL Server database.

I have a primary key that is a unique identifer (*guid*) in the destination table. So of course this cannot be null. In testing this I manually inserted a record in the table through a SQL insert statement. Saw that this worked so I went on to test the same query to be triggered by button click event. Which works. It will import the records from another table, and default to create a *guid*. However, upon further testing I came to realize that when I was working with an empty table it would not successfully import into another table. Access would run the query on the button click, but then warn me that no records would be transferred.

My question is why is that? What am I missing to properly insert a new record into a empty table? It only seems to work with a table with existing records.

Comment: This really depends on your exact setup, and what that query is doing. I don't think anyone can answer this question without further information

Comment: I am confused by "working with an empty table it would not successfully import into another table". Of course if a table is empty there are no records to import into another table. Then you say "insert a new record into a empty table". So it is the destination table that is empty and the import fails? That would be odd. Post query and code for analysis.

Comment: Ah , I did not phrase it correctly. I am attempting to insert a new record into an empty table. A sample version of the query goes like this...  INSERT INTO destTable ( DateEntered, FirstName, LastName )
SELECT sourceTable.DateCreated, sourceTable.FirstName, sourceTable.LastName
FROM sourceTable, destTable

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is a terminology issue.  Using Access' terminology; one would do this in 2 steps:  Use the query design view feature

a. Make a Select Query using the table of record(s) to be moved.  Save that with a name - I will name it Q1 for now.

b. Make an Append Query; begin by selecting Q1 as the record source - and when you identify it as an Append it will ask for the destination table and you'll select that.  Then you align the fields as appropriate.  Save this as A2 query.

Then all you need to do is fire the A2 query in an ongoing sense.

In Access terminology one has Select, Append, Update and not Insert - so although the SQL syntax of the Update query is indeed INSERT INTO all I can think of is possibly you were invoking the Update method which would of course require that there be a record to over write.

Hope this helps.